# BlueData - Kibana server is not ready yet

Tags: bluedata

I've followed the [instructions](http://docs.bluedata.com/40_accessing-kibana-monitoring) to add Kibana to my BlueData 4.0 controller:

- Login to the Controller.
- Execute the command `docker exec -it monitoring-<controller_ip> bash`, where  is the IP address of the Controller.
- Change the permissions of /etc/kibana/kibana.yml to 644.
- Obtain Kibana admin credentials by executing the following command:
  `bdconfig --getallenv | grep bdshared_elasticsearch_admin`

The system returns the username and password. For example:

```
export bdshared_elasticsearch_adminpass='adef3a31-fbec-474d-8b74-a50b3355399f';
export bdshared_elasticsearch_admin='elastic';
```

- Execute the command service kibana start.
- Open a web browser and navigate to `<A.B.C.D>:5610` to access the Kibana interface, where `<A.B.C.D>` is either the Controller IP address, cluster IP address (if platform HA is enabled), or the IP address of a Gateway host.
- Enter the credentials you obtained in Step 3, above.
- You may now access the Kibana interface.

However, when I try to access the service on the controller `A.B.C.D:5610` I get the following error (I have tried for about 15 minutes):

> Kibana server is not ready yet

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the primary controller (see note below), I tried to connect to elasticsearch:

```
[centos@ip-10-1-0-242 ~]$ curl localhost:9210
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:9210; Connection refused
```

It returned an error, so I found the epic-monitoring-** service ...

```
[centos@ip-10-1-0-242 ~]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
6e61f6a9eb5f        bluedata/sklearngpu:1.0         "/sbin/init"             2 weeks ago         Up 32 hours                             bluedata-15
35e029a991ea        epic/webhdfs:1.0                "/usr/bin/supervisord"   2 weeks ago         Up 32 hours                             epic-webhdfs-10.1.0.242
55f607fa361d        epic/monitoring:1.12            "/etc/start-all.sh..."   2 weeks ago         Up 32 hours                             epic-monitoring-10.1.0.242
15b5090844ed        epic/nagios:1.9                 "/bin/sh -c '/usr/..."   2 weeks ago         Up 32 hours                             epic-nagios-10.1.0.242
b380915b6c3b        epic/apache-hdfs-centos:2.7.2   "/usr/local/bin/st..."   2 weeks ago         Up 32 hours                             epic-apache-hdfs-centos
```

and restarted it:

```
[centos@ip-10-1-0-242 ~]$ docker restart 55f607fa361d
55f607fa361d
```

I then followed the [instructions](http://docs.bluedata.com/40_accessing-kibana-monitoring) again to enable kibana, and after waiting a few minutes, I was able to login to kibana with the credentials returned by `bdconfig --getallenv | grep bdshared_elasticsearch_admin`

---

**NOTE**:

To find the current primary controller run:

- `bdconfig --hainfo`, or
- check the BlueData UI Installation page - look for `Role: Primary Controller`

Comment: See also knowledge base https://bluedata.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/search/click?data=BAh7CjoHaWRsKwg5kP%2FRUwA6CXR5cGVJIgxhcnRpY2xlBjoGRVQ6CHVybEkiY2h0dHBzOi8vYmx1ZWRhdGEuemVuZGVzay5jb20vaGMvZW4tdXMvYXJ0aWNsZXMvMzYwMDA1NDcyMzEzLUluY3JlYXNpbmctRWxhc3RpY3NlYXJjaC1KYXZhLUhlYXAGOwdUOg5zZWFyY2hfaWRJIiliZWY2YWFhMC04YTIwLTRiMTEtOGNjOC1kMTYyNTE5NWYwZDMGOwdGOglyYW5raQY%3D--b4306e38c0b0c50ae096eafbcf6d515063a0e917 about elastic search stability